# Cannot set property 'filterPredicate' of undefined error in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material, observable

I have an Angular Material Table with client side filtering in which I'm retrieving data from a service. While my filters were working properly with hardcoded data, I'm getting an error saying : Cannot set property 'filterPredicate' of undefined ever since I've switched to retrieving data from a service. The data is visible in my table correctly but I'm not able to filter it.

```
export class MessageTableComponent implements OnInit {
    datasource: any;
}
    ngOnInit() {

        this.messageService.getMessageTableData().subscribe(
          response => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
            console.log(response);
          }
        );

        this.RequestIdFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((RequestIdFilterValue) => {
          this.filteredValues['RequestID'] = RequestIdFilterValue;
          this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
          });

          this.RequestStatusFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((RequestStatusFilterValue) => {
            this.filteredValues['RequestStatus'] = RequestStatusFilterValue;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
            });

          this.RequestorNameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((RequestorNameFilterValue) => {
            this.filteredValues['RequestorName'] = RequestorNameFilterValue;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
          });

          this.ApproverNameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((ApproverNameFilterValue) => {
            this.filteredValues['ApproverName'] = ApproverNameFilterValue;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
          });

          this.SubjectFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((SubjectFilterValue) => {
            this.filteredValues['Subject'] = SubjectFilterValue;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
          });

          this.MessageStatusFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((MessageStatusFilterValue) => {
            this.filteredValues['MessageStatus'] = MessageStatusFilterValue;
            this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
            });

            this.SubmissionFromDateFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((SubmissionFromDateFilterValue) => {
              this.filteredValues['SubmissionFromDate'] = SubmissionFromDateFilterValue;
              this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
            });

            this.SubmissionToDateFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((SubmissionToDateFilterValue) => {
              this.filteredValues['SubmissionToDate'] = SubmissionToDateFilterValue;
              this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
            });



        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();

        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;


      }

customFilterPredicate() {
.....
}
```

The error is apparently at the second last line. messageService is the service I'm using to retrieve the data and the rest of the code is to filter the data any time the value of any of the columns changes. Below this, I have my customFilterPredicate function defining the filters for each column.

I don't understand what's the issue. I have defined dataSource in ngOnInit so why is the error coming and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the call from your service hadn't returned when the this line " this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();" executed...

we know that Async calls can take time (compared to fetching hard-coded data)...

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

try placing these 2 lines (above) inside the service call finally block, i have included an error block also, which you should always have to handle any errors...

```
   this.messageService.getMessageTableData().subscribe(
          response => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
            console.log(response);
          }
          ,errorResponse => { console.log(errorResponse); }
          ,()=> { 
            this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            }
            );
```